# react-bootstarp warning about color adjust

Tags: react-bootstrap

I began my react app with create-react-app, then I installed react-bootstrap with npm, then I used in my index.js **import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';**.
After saved this wrning appeared:
[image]

What's wrong ?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 5):

**To fix it temporarily:**

Remove your "node_modules" folder
Remove your "package-lock.json" file
Add to your "package.json" file: "overrides": `{ "autoprefixer": "10.4.5" }`
Finally, run: `npm i --save-exact`

**Some details:**

React version: `^18.1.0`
Bootstrap: `^5.1.3`
cra-template: `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`
Node version: `v16.14.2`
NPM version: `8.6.0`
env: `macOS Monterey v12.3.1 | intel processor`

***Hope it works for u!***

Comment: Thanks! Everywhere suggested adding the "overrides" entry and claimed that that was enough, but I had to perform your added steps and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

There is a temporary bug, which will be fixed with bootstrap v5.2:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36259

You need to install autoprefixer 10.4.5:

```
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
```